# how to optimize multi join job

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

**How can I speed up my joins against CSV files?**

I've got a query that is joining 8 files:

```
//please note this is the simplified query
DECLARE ... //summarizing here
FROM ...
USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '|');

//8 more statements like the above ommitted

SELECT  one.an_episode_id, 
        one.id2_enc_kgb_id, 
        one.suffix, 
        two.suffixa, 
        three.suffixThree, 
        four.suffixFour, 
        five.suffixFive,
        six.suffixSix,
        seven.suffixSeven,
        eight.suffixEight,
        nine.suffixNine,
        ten.suffixTen  
FROM @one_files AS one
JOIN @two_files AS two 
  ON one.id3_enc_kgb_id == two.id3_enc_kgb_id
JOIN @three_files AS three  
  ON three.id3_enc_kgb_id == one.id3_enc_kgb_id
JOIN @four_files AS four
  ON four.id3_enc_kgb_id == one.id3_enc_kgb_id
JOIN @five_files AS five
  ON five.id3_enc_kgb_id == one.id3_enc_kgb_id
JOIN @six_files AS six
  ON six.id2_enc_kgb_id == one.id2_enc_kgb_id
JOIN @seven_files AS seven
  ON seven.id2_enc_kgb_id == one.id2_enc_kgb_id
JOIN @eight_files AS eight
  ON eight.id2_enc_kgb_id == one.id2_enc_kgb_id
JOIN @nine_files AS nine
  ON nine.id2_enc_kgb_id == one.id2_enc_kgb_id
JOIN @ten_files AS ten
  ON ten.id2_enc_kgb_id == one.id2_enc_kgb_id;
```

I submitted the job to Azure, and had to cancel it after a few hours and $80 in cost!

[image]

It was my understanding that Data Lake is meant *exactly* for this type of job?! I've got perhaps 100 files total, totaling maybe 20mb of data.

**How can I speed up my joins?**

Comment: Since you are using 32 AU's it would help if you do your joins separately so it can be paralleled to other AU's. You will have much more code but it can help.

Comment: you mean create intermediate files? what do you mean separate joins? could you provide example

Comment: I mean have multiple select joins and not all the joins in one select statement.

Comment: this is where it is stuck. i took your suggestion and yielded the same results. having more intermediate SELECTs didnt do anything https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1XL5WRQP9fKxuYhOxGtvVe9A-7B7tXBnv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is important for you to note that **small files** are **suboptimal** in every scenario.  The suggested solution for smaller files, by [Michal Rys](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrys/tag/u-sql) is to consider these alternative to concat them into large files:

- Offline outside of Azure
- Event Hubs Capture
- Stream Analytics
- or ADLA fast file sets to compact most recent deltas

Note:
[`fast file set`](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2018/2018_Spring/USQL_Release_Notes_2018_Spring.md#input-file-set-scales-orders-of-magnitudes-better-finally-released) allows you to consume hundreds of thousands of such files in bulk in a single `EXTRACT`.

I would use `INNER JOIN` instead of `JOIN` to be sure you know which join you are really using.

It is rather important to see how you have EXTRACTed the information from the CSV files.  The JOINed result should be OUTPUTed into a **tsv** ([Tab-Separated-Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/operators/outputters/outputters-tsv) - Note: **TVF** is [Table-Valued Functions](https://saveenr.gitbooks.io/usql-tutorial/content/usql-catalog/usql-table-valued-functions.html) for u-sql code reuse) file.

The TSV structure:

- TSV = Tab-Separated-Value
- It has no header row
- Each row has the same number of columns

This format should be very efficient for u-sql (I did not yet measure it myself).

To have complete information you can have three different build-in outputter types [.Text(), .Csv(), Tsv()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/operators/built-in-outputters).

Your example is missing the variables so I'll try to guess them

```
USE DATABASE <your_database>;
USE SCHEMA <your_schema>;

DECLARE @FirstCsvFile string = "/<path>/first.csv";
@firstFile = EXTRACT an_episode_id string, id2_enc_kgb_id string, suffix string
FROM @FirstCsvFile USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '|');

// probably 8 more statements which where omitted in the OP


@encode = SELECT  one.an_episode_id, 
                  one.id2_enc_kgb_id, 
                  one.suffix, 
                  two.suffixa, 
                  three.suffixThree, 
                  four.suffixFour, 
                  five.suffixFive,
                  six.suffixSix,
                  seven.suffixSeven,
                  eight.suffixEight,
                  nine.suffixNine,
                  ten.suffixTen  
          FROM @firstFile AS one
          INNER JOIN @two_files AS two 
            ON one.id3_enc_kgb_id == two.id3_enc_kgb_id
          INNER JOIN @three_files AS three  
            ON three.id3_enc_kgb_id == one.id3_enc_kgb_id
          INNER JOIN @four_files AS four
            ON four.id3_enc_kgb_id == one.id3_enc_kgb_id
          INNER JOIN @five_files AS five
            ON five.id3_enc_kgb_id == one.id3_enc_kgb_id
          INNER JOIN @six_files AS six
            ON six.id2_enc_kgb_id == one.id2_enc_kgb_id
          INNER JOIN @seven_files AS seven
            ON seven.id2_enc_kgb_id == one.id2_enc_kgb_id
          INNER JOIN @eight_files AS eight
            ON eight.id2_enc_kgb_id == one.id2_enc_kgb_id
          INNER JOIN @nine_files AS nine
            ON nine.id2_enc_kgb_id == one.id2_enc_kgb_id
          INNER JOIN @ten_files AS ten
            ON ten.id2_enc_kgb_id == one.id2_enc_kgb_id;
 OUTPUT @encode TO "/outputs/encode_joins.tsv" USING Outputters.Tsv();
```

Comment: Wonderful answer thank you very much. Why are small files bad? Why should the output be tsv?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' You are welcome.  For too many small files (what is the trashold, is individual).  Quering too many small files will have much greater operations overhead (find file, open, parse, joining them etc.).  If you have larger files you can don't have this overhead.  As for *tsv* (see my edit), the reason being that it should be efficient way to output data (in the edited answer you have link to the other 2 build-in outputers) - in the original text I have had a typo TVF (Table-Valued function) used to prevent code duplication and TSV which is an file output format.

Comment: Understood. What are fast file sets?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' - fast file set allows you to consume hundreds of thousands of such files in bulk in a single `EXTRACT`.  For more see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/2018/06/11/azure-data-lake-analytics-and-u-sql-spring-2018-updates-parquet-support-small-files-dynamic-output-fast-file-sets-and-much-more/ and  how to turn it on https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2018/2018_Spring/USQL_Release_Notes_2018_Spring.md#input-file-set-scales-orders-of-magnitudes-better-finally-released

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' why did you split the select?  I'm not sure that saving & reading (`@finalData`) from the same variable is wise thing to do, I would use different name to avoid any issues.

Comment: the other issue im having right now is that instead of using the actual VALUE for  a given field, it's actually returning the field name ! https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1ZOE46UzuJz4nGNruX45U1l5v_NRsJH-4

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I think we need to have a chat room for this discussion - join me at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199288/room-for-tukan-and-l